# Design slides for presentation (conference talk)

Tags: soft-question, advice, conferences

> Question: What are approved guidelines for design good slides for a
>   conference talk, especially with focus on mathematics?

I'm aware of the following, general best practices for holding a presentation:

- (*) No full sentences, just bullet points or key words
- (*) Visualize concepts by images
- (*) Skip the too-complicated things and details
- Just cover one idea/topic on one slide
- Big font size
- ...

While some of these guidelines also apply to a mathematics talk, I have problems with the stared points. In mathematics concreteness and exactness are very important. Hand waving, imprecise and sketchy slides seem to contradict these paradigms. Often I've attended talks with lots of definitions and theorems which were copied 1:1 from the original publication. This form of presentation is too pedantic in my opinion and I was wondering about how to find the happy medium.

PS: I also appreciate links to good examples of presentation slides.

Comment: Two guides you've probably seen, but worth mentioning:

Jordan Ellenberg's tips on giving talks -- http://www.math.wisc.edu/~ellenber/mntcg/TalkTipSheet.pdf; as well as some by Terence Tao: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/talks-are-not-the-same-as-papers/

Comment: Why is this question off-topic? What is more relevant to a researcher than to present their own work in a good and comprehensible way? (Also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29866/presenting-a-paper-dos-and-donts?rq=1 is a comparable question, just that my current question is more about the slides and not the whole talk)